# How to store images in a list from image folder and passing it to image src in (asp.net| vb.net)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, list, stringbuilder

I have got two image folders namely a and b which consist of images of products. All images are save as there productid. how can can i find the images from a folder by passing there
 productid and save the images in a list.

```
Dim AllImages As New List(Of String)
```

After saving it , how can i render those images one by one into string builder like

```
Dim imagecontainer As New StringBuilder
 For Each image In AllImages
imagecontainer.Append("<img src="image" alt="" />") Next image

Any ideas of how to do this, your help will be highly appreciated.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ResolveClientUrl within your page code-behind:

```
var clientImageUrl = ResolveClientUrl("yourimagefolder/sampleimage.jpg");
```

Or you can use VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute that will return the same result :

```
VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("yourimagefolder/sampleimage.jpg")
```

In order to read all the files from a folder and then filter them by file name (your ID) you can use (use the System.IO namespace) :

```
 DirectoryInfo directory = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo("c:\YourFolder");
 var allFiles = directory.GetFiles(".", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);

 var fileFounds = from file in allFiles 
                  where file.Name == "YourID"
                  select file;
```

foreach (var file in fileFounds)
{
    //Build your image
}

**EDIT**: here's the vb.net version (I've used a code converter, hope it worked well: )

```
'Using ResolveClientUrl 
Dim clientImageUrl = ResolveClientUrl("yourimagefolder/sampleimage.jpg")
```

'Using VirtualPathUtility
VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("yourimagefolder/sampleimage.jpg")

'Reading files from directory
Dim directory As DirectoryInfo = New System.IO.DirectoryInfo("c:\YourFolder")
Dim allFiles = directory.GetFiles(".", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)

Dim fileFounds = _
    Where file.Name = "YourID"

```
    'Build your image
```

For Each file As var In fileFounds
Next

Comment: will give it a try after getting home

Comment: filefounds is a list or any arraylist

Comment: It is an array of FileInfo, you can easily cast it to a list with the ToList() method on the array.

Answer (score 1):

- Use [DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx) to get all files in a directory
- Use your foreach loop to build the html
- Add a [PlaceHolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.placeholder.aspx) to your page and add your html to it

Or, you could use a [Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx) bound to a list of image path strings. This will give you much more control over your markup.

Here's an example with a Repeater.

Markup:

```
<asp:Repeater id="imageRepeater" runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
     <img src='<%# Container.DataItem %>' alt="" />
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Codebehind:

```
imageRepeater.DataSource = imageFiles
imageRepeater.DataBind()
```

Comment: can you give me a short example , that will be of great help